# I would like to add condition to change Image in this script or create new

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to change image by use `val["id"]` to define the condition:

```
if (val["id"] > 10) {
    //show the first image
} else if (val["id"] > 20) {
    //show the second image
} else {
    //show the third image
};
```

I don't understand some syntax of ajax can you help me to done with above condition

```
function getDataFromDb() {
    $.ajax({
            url: "getData.php",
            type: "POST",

        })
        .success(function(result) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
            if (obj != '') {
                //$("#myTable tbody tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
                $("#myBody").empty();
                $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
                    var tr = "<tr>";
                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["id"] + "</td>";
                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["first_name"] + "</td>";
                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["last_name"] + "</td>";
                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["age"] + "</td>";
                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["hometown"] + "</td>";
                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["job"] + "</td>";
                    tr = tr + "</tr>";
                    $('#myTable > tbody:last').append(tr);
                });
            }

        });

}

setInterval(getDataFromDb, 100); // 1000 = 1 second
```

Comment: When do you want to do your conditional check??

Comment: refer this link - > http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: `if (val["id"] > 10) tr = tr + "<img src='" + location + "'>";` ? Other than that you'll need to elaborate more.

Comment: You need to change you condition i.e if (val["id"] < 10) because, at the moment, only the first condition will be used for values > 10

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help.

```
function getDataFromDb() {
$.ajax({
        url: "getData.php",
        type: "POST",

    })
    .success(function(result) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        if (obj != '') {
            //$("#myTable tbody tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
            $("#myBody").empty();
            $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
                var tr = "<tr>";
                tr = tr + "<td>" + val["id"] + "</td>";
                tr = tr + "<td>" + val["first_name"] + "</td>";
                tr = tr + "<td>" + val["last_name"] + "</td>";
                tr = tr + "<td>" + val["age"] + "</td>";
                tr = tr + "<td>" + val["hometown"] + "</td>";
                tr = tr + "<td>" + val["job"] + "</td>";
                tr = tr + "<td>" + "<img src='" + GetImage(parseInt(val["id"]))+ "'>" + "</td>";
                tr = tr + "</tr>";
                $('#myTable > tbody:last').append(tr);
            });
        }

    });
```

}

```
function GetImage(id){
  if (val["id"] < 10) {
    return "images/img01.jpg"; // edit this to which works for you
   } else if (val["id"] < 20) {
    return "images/img02.jpg"
   } else {
    return "images/img03.jpg"
  };
}

setInterval(getDataFromDb, 100); // 1000 = 1 second
```

The function assumes that if the Id is less than 10 then show first if its less than 20 show second else 3rd. Your initial logic would show the first image if the id was 10+ that is to inifnity...

Comment: It doesn't show any result. I will post all of my source code.

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST REAL TIME UPDATE</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<script>

function getDataFromDb()
{
    $.ajax({ 
                url: "getData.php" ,
                type: "POST",
                data: ''
            })
            .success(function(result) { 
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                    if(obj != '')
                    {
                          //$("#myTable tbody tr:not(:first-child)").remove();
                          $("#myBody").empty();
                          $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
                                    var tr = "<tr>";
                                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["id"] + "</td>";
                                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["first_name"] + "</td>";
                                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["last_name"] + "</td>";
                                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["age"] + "</td>";
                                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["hometown"] + "</td>";
                                    tr = tr + "<td>" + val["job"] + "</td>";
                                    // tr = tr + "<td>" + "<img src='" + GetImage(parseInt(val["id"]))+"'>" + "</td>";
                                    tr = tr + "</tr>";
                                    $('#myTable > tbody:last').append(tr);
                          });
                    }

            });

}

// function GetImage(id){
//  if (val["id"] < 10){
//      return "pic/img1.jpg"
//  } else if (val["id"] < 20){
//      return "pic/img2.jpg"
//  } else {
//      return "pic/img3.jpg"
//  };
// }

setInterval(getDataFromDb, 100);   // 1000 = 1 second
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <center>
<h1>TEST AJAX CHANGE PICTURE</h1>
</br>

<table width="600" border="1" id="myTable">
<!-- head table -->
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td width="91"> <div align="center">ID </div></td>
    <td width="98"> <div align="center">First_Name </div></td>
    <td width="198"> <div align="center">Last_Name</div></td>
    <td width="97"> <div align="center">Age </div></td>
    <td width="59"> <div align="center">Hometown </div></td>
    <td width="71"> <div align="center">Job </div></td>
    <!-- <td width="198"> <div align="center"> Pic</div></td> -->
  </tr>
</thead>
<!-- body dynamic rows -->
<tbody id="myBody"></tbody>
</table>




 <center>
</body>
</html>
```

getData.php

```
<?php
    $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    $objDB = mysql_select_db("ajax_demo");
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM my_db WHERE 1 ORDER BY id DESC limit 1 ";
    $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die (mysql_error());
    $intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
    $resultArray = array();
    while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
    {
        $arrCol = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
        {
            $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
        }
        array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
    }

    mysql_close($objConnect);

    echo json_encode($resultArray);
?>
```